# Validate Textbox for Duplicate ListViewItems

Tags: vb.net, validation, listview

I have 4 textboxes that I use to fill a ListView. I need the 4th textbox to verify that the data is not already in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the list and verify each cell. I'm not sure how you submit your items but I'll assume it's in a `Button_Click` event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'I'll store "abc" in TextBox4.Text for my example
    TextBox4.Text = "abc"

    'First we loop through each listview item (or row)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        'For each item, we will loop through it's subitems
        For Each subItem As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem In item.SubItems
            'If textbox4.text is equal to the current subitem, we've found that the item already exists
            If Textbox4.Text = subItem.Text Then
                MsgBox("Item abc is already in the list")
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly, I use a button_click! Basically, when I enter the data on the first textbox and hit Enter, it will move to the next one. When I get to the last one and hit enter, I have something like this:                 If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
                    btnAgregar_Click(sender, e)
                End If                                             If I understand, I have to validate on the Buttton_Click, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Find method, `ListView1.Items.Find("myString", True)`.  That will search each item and all their subitems.

Instead of calling the button click handler directly, it's probably better to use the PerformClick method of the specific button.

Comment: What if the data entered on the textbox is something like an ID (or a social security number) that no one else is supposed have? Will it work the same way?

Comment: I was able to apply your first answer. I added it to a different metod and called it from the Button_Click. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: The Find method saves a lot of extra coding.  Simply check if the return item array count is 0 to see if there was no match.